# Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy certificate

Tags: jmeter, digital-certificate

I have imported the certificate in firefox which got generated.

But still in "View Result Tree" getting the below error, and page in firefox also not opening:

Response message: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
**ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy certificate**

I have followed below steps:

Choose the following options:

```
Tools / Options
Advanced / Certificates
View Certificates
Authorities
Import …
Browse to the JMeter launch directory, and click on the file ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt, press Open
Click View and check that the certificate details agree with the ones displayed by the JMeter Test Script Recorder
If OK, select "Trust this CA to identify web sites", and press OK
Close dialogs by pressing OK as necessary
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things to check:

- If you added the certificates 6 days ago, ensure you add it again as it expires by default after some delay that can be tuned with:

> proxy.cert.validity=7

- Another possibility is that there is an SSL algo mistmatch between Java version of JMeter and server version. This would be adjusted in java.security.

Comment: Seems you are talking about this bug - https://github.com/apache/jmeter/issues/3352 
1. this issue is already closed 
2. why SSL algo would cause an issue with different client and server Java version mismatch?